# How to animate an image in WPF with a mousedown event on the canvas or window

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mouseevent, animated

I have a window with a canvas using WPF and C#. On the canvas I have an image. I want to apply a mousedown event to the window or canvas that will animate the image left or right depending upon which mouse button is clicked. Left mouse button should move the image left and right mouse button should move the image to the right. The movement should stop when the button is no longer down. I have done this in winforms using a timer, but Im just starting to work with WPF and I cant seem to find any examples of mouse triggered animation. Can anyone help out a WPF newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done by starting Storyboards on EventTriggers:

```
<Canvas Background="White">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MoveLeft" TargetName="imageView" TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
            <DoubleAnimation To="50" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MoveRight" TargetName="imageView" TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
            <DoubleAnimation To="250" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Restore" TargetName="imageView" TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
            <DoubleAnimation To="150" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveLeft}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseRightButtonDown">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MoveRight}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseRightButtonUp">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Restore}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Restore}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>

    <Image Width="200" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="90" x:Name="imageView" Source="floppydisk.jpg"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks Joulukuusi. So it is done in XML... Hmmm... This seems to only register the mouse event on the image, though. Can the window or canvas be used to register the mouse event that would make the image move?

Comment: Sorry, I found that if the canvas background is set to null (which is the default), the mouse events wont register. I changed it to transparent and all works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @ClamsCasino, sure. These four events are `RoutedEvent`s, which means their parents also receive notifications (so you can remove the "Image." part). And yes, the Canvas must have background set in order to receive these events.

Comment: This was very helpful in understanding the xaml side, but Im really trying to get it done on the C# side where I can manipulate a bunch of animations. I've just installed expression blend, hopefully that will give me more insight on animation in wpf. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found that MS Expression Blend was easy to use and created the xaml. I also found that items can be created and animated in the code file.